# Server-client file transfer null pointer exception

Tags: java, sockets, nullpointerexception, file-transfer

I'm developing a server to client file transfer program on java, and couldn't figure out how to fix the following code as I don't know much about socket programming. The code is Client side's codes:

```
String receiverIP = null;
    int serverPort = 0;
    hostIP = args[0];
    serverPort = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    String fileToSend = args[2]; 
    byte[] aByte = new byte[1];
    int bytesR;
    Socket clientSocket = null;
    Socket connectSocket = null;
    BufferedOutputStream ToClient = null;
    InputStream is = null;

    try {
        ToClient = new BufferedOutputStream(connectSocket.getOutputStream());
        clientSocket = new Socket(hostIP, serverPort);
        is = clientSocket.getInputStream();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
```

as for my problem, I get a null pointer exception on line 14 (undoubtedly since currently connectSocket is null), but I have no idea what can I assign on connectSocket(if it was on server side a connection accept socket could've been assigned to begin writing after the connecion is established.)

Comment: What use is `ToClient`? What is the difference between it and `is`?

Comment: ToClient fills in the bytearray with the acquired file size below this code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contrary to what you seem to believe, you do not need two separate sockets to read and write to the server. One socket will suffice. You can call the `getInputStream` method to get a stream to read from the server, and `getOutputStream` to get a stream to write to the server. You don't need two sockets, just one.

Comment: as a beginner to socket programming, it's been quite helpful to know that, as I thought 1 socket will focus on reading and 1 for writing